# Cakephp: How to handle exception if action is missing

Tags: php, exception, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I am developing an Api in Cakephp. I need to handle the exception if android app calls wrong function or wrong controller. I need to know how can I can handle that and return the response in json to my android app. I mean I know I can write something in my `beforefilter` function because this function will execute first But I don't know how I can catch first the exception or how can I detect the event. By Googling I come to some solution but still it is not working. Here is my code below which I have tried.

App/Lib/AppErrorHandler.php

```
 class AppErrorHandler extends ExceptionRenderer{
  public static function handleException($error) {
        if ($error instanceof MissingActionException) {

          echo "incorrect controller action name";
            exit;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

in bootstrap.php

```
App::uses('AppErrorHandler', 'Lib');
```

I didn't do anything in my Api regarding exception. Please let me know if I have to write some code in Api class too

Comment: Did you read the docs here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html ? I'm not sure I see a specific question otherwise. What is it that you're having trouble with?

Comment: how does your app call the API? does it use the .json notation? if so cakephp gives errors as json back

Answer (score 0):

You are extending ExceptionRenderer for your custom ExceptionHandler, which is the right way. Now you are trying to override method **handleException** which basically is not present in the baseClass. So Its wrong to do that..

Now for your solution:
You need to override function render() from ExceptionRenderer class. The way you do it is below:

```
class AppErrorHandler extends ExceptionRenderer{
    public function render() {       
        if ($this->method) {            
            if($this->error instanceof MissingActionException) {
                // echo here whatever you want..
            }
            call_user_func_array(array($this, $this->method), array($this->error));    
            // this line is required to render the normal page as per the error code.. 400 or 500 or similar..
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S:** in lib/Cake/Error you will find the files which handle the default exceptions. Here in exceptions.php you will find the different errors which are thrown or can be thrown.